# jquery traverse through DOM

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to reach an area in the DOM and I can't quite seem to target it with jquery.

The HTML looks like:

```
<h4>stuff here</h4>

<div class="answerDiv">
    <div class="ExternalClass">
        <p>
            Need to expand or show this.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>more stuff here</h4>

<div class="answerDiv">
    <div class="ExternalClass">
        <p>
            Need to expand or show this.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target and expand the areas that say "Need to expand or show this."

I've tried a ton of different variations of jQuery selectors:

```
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('h4').slideToggle();
$(this).next().next().slideToggle();
$(this).next(".answerDiv").show();
```

onlcick method:

```
$('h4').click(function () {
$(this).next(".answerDiv").show();
})
```

I'm using CSS to hide the .answerDiv class by default.

The full code:

```
    <script src="/mapres/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='~/css/faq.css' />

  <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 populateFAQ();
 $(".answerDiv").hide(); 
  toggleContentHeaders();


 });





 function toggleContentHeaders() {
 $('h4').click(function () {
$(this).next(".answerDiv").show();
});
}



function populateFAQ() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ')/items?$orderby=ID desc",
       method: "GET",
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
       success: function (data) {
           $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item){
               $("#faqDiv").append(

      "<h4>" + " " + this.Title + "</h4>" +
      "<div class='answerDiv'>" + this.Answer + "</div>"

      );


        });
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      }

      });

   }

 </script>



 <body style="background-color:#e3e1e2;">
 <div id="faqDiv">
</body>
```

***UPDATED***

I was able to fix this by nesting the functions within the ajax function instead of document ready

```
function populateFAQ() {
    $.ajax({
         url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ')/items?$orderby=ID desc",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item){
               $("#faqDiv").append(

        "<h4>" + " " + this.Title + "</h4>" +
        "<div class='answerDiv'>" + this.Answer + "</div>"

        );

          });
        $(".answerDiv").hide();   //hidden here
            toggleContentHeaders() //added function here
        },
         error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

         });

      }

 </script>
```

Comment: what is `this` referring to?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is jQuery included? Are you loading your jQuery  code in a document ready handler or at the end of the document? At the very least, `$(this).next(".answerDiv").show()` would work. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: this is the h4 element

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I code it like the following:   <h4>stuff</h4><div>stuff</div> and use a slidetoggle.

Comment: And for that I use $(this).next().slideToggle();

Comment: Your code works, I tested it in jsFiddle:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".answerDiv").hide();
    $('h4').click(function () {
    $(this).next(".answerDiv").show();
    })
});

Comment: What i posted originally was the DOM result of the code.  I do a REST query to generate the DOM structure with an $.each loop.  This creates the structure above.

Comment: Ok I got it working.  I had to nest the JS functions within the ajax function instead of document ready.